# Derived H160 address is different than showing in metamask?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, frontier, ethereum

I know ss58 public key and private key, also I have derived the EVM HS160 account from the same public key, next is how I can import that EVM HS160 Account in metamask. If I put the private key of ss58 address, It points to some different HS160 Account Address from What I have derived.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the deriving algorithm.

```
// sr25519
privatek --f(privatek)--> publick1
// ecdsa
privatek --g(privatek)--> publick2
// derived ecdsa (from sr25519)
privatek --f(privatek)--> publick1 --derive(publick1)--> publick3
```

During the process that I show above. IMO, `publick1 == publick3` is impossible.

And I don't recommend you use the same private key everywhere.